# Is there any way to check if ConstantExpression containing number is negative?

Tags: .net, expression-trees, linq-expressions

I have the following expression

```
int someNumber = somevalue;
ConstantExpression expr = Expression.Constant(someNumber);
```

Is there a way to check to see if expr < 0 or expr is a negative number ?

Comment: Do you want to build an _expression_ that performs this comparison, or do you just want to analyze the constant value directly in your C# code?

Comment: I want to analyze if this ConstantExpression has numeric value inside (like decimal, int or double) and see if that value is negative.

Comment: Yes, but do you want to do this analysis directly in your C# code, or do you want to compose an expression tree that performs that logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the type of the constant, you can simply cast and analyze the underlying constant value.

```
ConstantExpression expr = /* ... */;
var intConstant = expr.Value as int?;
if (intConstant < 0) { /* do something */ }
```

Naturally, if all you have is an `Expression`, you will need to inspect it to determine whether it *is* a `ConstantExpression`.

If you don't know the type, but you want to check any valid numeric type:

```
ConstantExpression expr = /* ... */;

if (expr.Value != null && expr.Value.GetType().IsNumericType()) {
    // Perform an appropriate comparison _somehow_, but not necessarily like this
    // (using Convert makes my skin crawl).
    var decimalValue = Convert.ToDecimal(expr.Value);
    if (decimalValue < 0m) { /* do something */ }
}
```

Extension methods used in second example:

```
public static Type GetNonNullableType([NotNull] this Type type)
{
    if (type == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("type");

    if (!type.IsGenericType || type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(Nullable<>))
        return type;

    return type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
}

public static bool IsNumericType(this Type type)
{
    if (type == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("type");

    type = type.GetNonNullableType();

    if (type.IsEnum)
        return false;

    switch (Type.GetTypeCode(type))
    {
        case TypeCode.SByte:
        case TypeCode.Byte:
        case TypeCode.Int16:
        case TypeCode.UInt16:
        case TypeCode.Int32:
        case TypeCode.UInt32:
        case TypeCode.Int64:
        case TypeCode.UInt64:
        case TypeCode.Single:
        case TypeCode.Double:
        case TypeCode.Decimal:
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `as` in cases like this. If the value has different type, you want to immediately get a clear exception.

Comment: I make no assumptions about what the OP deems to be desirable behavior or valid input.  He asked how to isolate negative numbers; he said nothing about all values having to be numbers.  I leave it to him to best decide how to check for and deal with unexpected values.